# LINQ to SQL Table Extensibility Methods

Tags: linq-to-sql, extensibility

If I have a LINQ to SQL table that has a field called say Alias.

There is then a method stub called OnAliasChanging(string value);

What I want to do is to grab the value, check the database whether the value already exists and then set the value to the already entered value.

So I may be changing my alias from "griegs" to "slappy" and if slappy exists then I want to revert to the already existing value of "griegs".

So I have;

```
    partial void OnaliasChanging(string value)
    {
        string prevValue = this.alias;
        this.Changed = true;
    }
```

When I check the value of prevValue it's always null.

How can I get the current value of a field?

**Update**

If I implement something like;

```
    partial void OnaliasChanging(string value)
    {
        if (this.alias != null)
            this.alias = "TEST VALUE";
    }
```

it goes into an infinte loop which is unhealthy.

If I include a check to see whether alias already == "TEST VALUE" the infinate loop still remains as the value is always the original value.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippets you've posted don't lend themselves to any plausible explanation of why you'd end up with an infinite loop.  I'm thinking that `this.alias` might be a property, as opposed to a field as the character casing would imply, but would need to see more.  If it is a property, then you are invoking the `OnAliasChanging` method before the property is ever set; therefore, trying to set it again in the same method will always cause an infinite loop.  Normally the way to design this scenario is to either implement a `Cancel` property in your `OnXyzChanging` `EventArgs` derivative, or save the old value in the `OnXyzChanging` method and subsequently perform the check/rollback in the `OnXyzChanged` method if you can't use the first (better) option.

Fundamentally, though, what you're trying to do is not very good design in general and goes against the principles of Linq to SQL specifically.  A Linq to SQL entity is supposed to be a POCO with no awareness of sibling entities or the underlying database at all.  To perform a dupe-check on every property change not only requires access to the `DataContext` or `SqlConnection`, but also causes what could technically be called a side-effect (opening up a new database connection and/or silently discarding the property change).  This kind of design just screams for mysterious crashes down the road.

In fact, your particular scenario is one of the main reasons why the `DataContext` class was made extensible in the first place.  This type of operation belongs in there.  Let's say that the entity here is called `User` with table `Users`.

```
partial class MyDataContext
{
    public bool ChangeAlias(Guid userID, string newAlias)
    {
        User userToChange = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == userID);
        if ((userToChange == null) || Users.Any(u => u.Alias == newAlias))
        {
            return false;
        }
        userToChange.Alias = newAlias;

        // Optional - remove if consumer will make additional changes
        SubmitChanges();

        return true;
    }
}
```

This encapsulates the operation you want to perform, but doesn't prevent consumers from changing the `Alias` property directly.  **If you can live with this, I would stop right there** - you should still have a UNIQUE constraint in your database itself, so this method can simply be documented and used as a *safe* way to attempt a name-change without risking a constraint violation later on (although there is always *some* risk - you can still have a race condition unless you put this all into a transaction or stored procedure).

If you absolutely *must* limit access to the underlying property, one way to do this is to hide the original property and make a read-only wrapper.  In the Linq designer, click on the `Alias` property, and on the property sheet, change the **Access** to `Internal` and the **Name** to `AliasInternal` (but don't touch the **Source**!).  Finally, create a partial class for the entity (I would do this in the same file as the `MyDataContext` partial class) and write a read-only wrapper for the property:

```
partial class User
{
    public string Alias
    {
        get { return AliasInternal; }
    }
}
```

You'll also have to update the `Alias` references in our `ChangeAlias` method to `AliasInternal`.

Be aware that this may break queries that try to filter/group on the new `Alias` wrapper (I believe Linq will complain that it can't find a SQL mapping).  The property itself will work fine as an accessor, but if you need to perform lookups on the `Alias` then you will likely need another `GetUserByAlias` helper method in `MyDataContext`, one which can perform the "real" query on `AliasInternal`.

Things start to get a little dicey when you decide you want to mess with the data-access logic of Linq in addition to the domain logic, which is why I recommend above that you just leave the `Alias` property alone and document its usage appropriately.  Linq is designed around optimistic concurrency; typically when you need to enforce a UNIQUE constraint in your application, you wait until the changes are actually saved and then handle the constraint violation if it happens.  If you want to do it immediately your task becomes harder, which is the reason for this verbosity and general kludginess.

One more time - I'm recommending *against* the additional step of creating the read-only wrapper; I've put up some code anyway in case your spec requires it for some reason.

Comment: +1 Thanks @Aaron.  1 question on your implementation.  Are you suggesting that I change the property in my data contests designer.cs file?  I'm a little hesitant in doing that given that if I add a table using the designer then my change will be lost.  thanks

Comment: No, you can't change the designer file, it's auto-generated.  You make a new file with the partial class.  If you right-click on the designer surface and click "View Code", it will do this for you.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure if I completely answered your question - assuming you're using the designer, you probably can't change the setter to internal, but you can change the "Access" of that property from "Public" to "Protected Internal", then make a partial class of the entity itself to create the read-only wrapper (only necessary if you are exposing this to external assemblies).

Comment: @Aaron, I hate to sound stupid here but is there any chance you can post a bit of code?  I understand the ChangeAlias method you provided but how do I do a ready only wrapper from the partial class of the User object on a property within it?

Comment: I've updated the post with more info.  FWIW, I think it's best to create the utility method in your `DataContext` but leave the property itself alone; you're still enforcing uniqueness at the DB level (I assume).

Answer (score 0):

Is it getting hung up because OnaliasChanging is firing during initialization, so your backing field (alias) never gets initialized so it is always null?

Without more context, that's what it sounds like to me.